# Recovering an HDD after using dd on it

Tags: linux, windows, dd, hard-drive-recovery

I accidentally used `dd` on my HDD (`/dev/sdc`) when I wanted to put an ISO on a USB drive.  I tried looking around and read that if the data was overwritten then I'm screwed....

Is there a way to recover the data?  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: An ISO has a limited size, do only that amount of the hard disc will have been overwritten. You can try partition recovery software (eg `testdisk`) and see what partitions are intact. You will need to boot a live CD and may need to install the recovery software after booting it.

Comment: Precisely what dd command did you run?

Comment: I used the command: dd bs=4M of=file if=/dev/sdc

Comment: You mean: "if=file of=/dev/sdc" ?

Because if you actually did "of=file" then it shouldn't have touched your sdc partition at all.

Comment: You're right, it was a typo

Comment: You should absolutely include the exact (and correct ;)) `dd` command used directly in the question. It is essential information to assess the damage. Also tell us how large the input file was.

Answer (score 1):

Data Destroyer overwrites the sectors on the hard drive.  There is no way to recover overwritten sectors.  Because of the way that Linux distributes files among sectors (which is why ext partitions don't need to be defragmented) it is unlikely that all the contents of a majority of your files survived.  Restore from back-ups, you did create them right?  And if you didn't you just learned why you should.  Sorry.

Comment: Not Data Destroyer, dd. From wikipedia: "The name dd is an allusion to the DD statement found in IBM's Job Control Language (JCL), in which the initials stand for "Data Description". The command's syntax resembles the JCL statement more than it does other Unix commands, so the syntax may have been a joke."

Comment: "Data Destroyer" is "what it does" when carelessly used.  As in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The data can only be saved if some or most of it's still there.

Here is a simple brute-force live test (using **pv** and **lzop**) to see how far (and how much) **dd** got:

```
hd=/dev/sdc   # change to whatever device or partition needs testing.
pv -EcN raw ${hd} | lzop |  pv -cN compressed | wc -c
```

On a 160GB hard drive that hasn't been wiped by **dd**, after a minute the test looks like this:

```
raw: 5.12GiB 0:01:11 [46.1MiB/s] [==>              ]  3% ETA 0:33:15
compressed: 4.81GiB 0:01:11 [45.9MiB/s] [    <=>         ]
```

Note how the *compressed* number is pretty close to the *raw* number.  As long as that's the case when the job is done, then most of the data still exists.  The percentage would vary according to how full the hard drive was before the trouble happened, i.e. if the HD or partition was only 10% full, then 8% from **lzop** would be normal.  It also depends what kind of data was filling the HD -- fortunately **lzop** is a weak compressor, which helps a lot here.

Let's try it with all zeros:

```
hd=/dev/zero   # change to whatever device or partition needs testing.
pv -cN raw ${hd} | lzop |  pv -cN compressed | wc -c
```

...which after 8 seconds shows:

```
raw: 6.81GiB 0:00:08 [ 891MiB/s] [   <=>                  ]
compressed: 31.8MiB 0:00:08 [4.06MiB/s] [     <=>         ]
```

The *compressed* size is now less than 1% of *raw*.  If an entire hard drive is like that, the data is *kaput*.

(Note:  it takes more time to read bigger hard drives, so this method would be improved by sampling.  Instead of reading every block, we might use **dd** to read *n* blocks, skip ahead *10n* blocks, and feed that to the *raw* input above.)